# How to bind extra data besides value in a set of radio buttons in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue to create a product table with their price list. Basically, I have a set of radio buttons which I use to change the product and then display a list of prices for that particular product.
It works, but I would like to get additional data for each product besides the id. I'm trying to bind a property, `hasFrame`, but I'm not sure how to use it.

This is the html for the product list:

```
<ul>
<li v-for="productType in productTypes"
    v-bind:class="{'is-selected': isSelected(productType.id) }">
  <label>
    <input type="radio"
           class="o-radio-hidden"
           name="product-type"
           v-model="selectedProductType"
           @change="changeProduct(productType)"
           v-bind:value="productType.id"
           v-bind:hasFrame="productType.has_frame">
    <span class="product-name">{{ productType.name }}</span>
  </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Then in the html there's a table where I'll display the prices, but it's not really related to the issue I have here so I left it out.

Here's the Javascript part:

```
  let vf = new Vue({
    el: '#product-table',
    data: {
      productTypes: [],
      productType: [],
      selectedProductType: [],
      hasFrame: 0,
    },
    methods: {
       getProductTypesList() {
           axiosInstance.get('ajax/getProductTypesList')
               .then((response) => {
                   this.productTypes = response.data;
           });
      },
      isSelected(productTypeId) {
        return productTypeId === this.selectedProductType;
      },
      changeProduct(productType) {
        this.hasFrame = productType.has_frame; // how to avoid this?
        this.getProductsData();
      },
    mounted() {
      this.selectedProductType = currentProductTypeId || 5;
      this.getProductTypesList();
      this.getProductsData();
    },
  });
```

The method `getProductTypesList()` returns an array of objects with this structure:

```
{
  "name": "Product name",
  "id": 1,
  "has_frame": 1 // boolean
}
```

So, inside `changeProduct` I'm updating the property `hasFrame` manually. Is there a way to avoid it and have the property to change automatically when the product changes?

Answer (score 0):

You declare `productType` as a `data` item, but you don't set it. Similarly, you declare `hasFrame`, but you don't use it. You do bind `productType.has_frame` (where `productType` is a parameter, and not a `data` item), which should work fine.

`changeProduct` should set `this.productType` (which should not be an array). Then `hasFrame`, if you wanted to be able to refer to it as such instead of `this.productType.has_frame`, could be a simple computed:

```
hasFrame() {
  return this.productType.has_frame;
}
```